# Referencing CLR Project in SQL Server 2012 SSDT Solution

Tags: sql-server, clr, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to upgrade a SQL Server 2008 dbproj to a SQL Server 2012 sqlproj using SSDT. Everything seems to be going ok, accept for the CLR project that is in the solution. I have it referenced in my sqlproj, but when I try and build, all of the locations that it is used in the project (see example below) are throwing errors: "blah blah blah has an unresolved reference to assembly []". Is there a special way I need to be referencing the CLR project so that the files in the sqlproj can use it? The CLR project worked fine in the 2008 dbproj...

```
CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[ConcatenateAll]
(@value NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXTERNAL NAME [Rma.Pass.Database.SqlClrUtility].[Rma.Pass.Database.SqlClrUtility.Aggregates.ConcatenateAll]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was something wrong in the way that the reference was created in my .sqlproj file. I created a new project and copied the ProjectReference xml settings from there, and was able to successfully build my project.